# How to completely remove nginx from ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I know this question has been asked earlier as well and I have gone through them but it does not solve my problem.

To remove nginx from system I executed following commands

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx

sudo apt-get purge nginx
```

Which actually uninstalled everything but when I do `nginx -V` it still returns following ...

> nginx version: nginx/1.4.1
>   built by gcc 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 
>   TLS SNI support enabled
>   configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_spdy_module

Also `ps aux | grep nginx` is not showing any nginx service running.

Now I am not sure that if I have completely removed nginx or not? If not then how to remove it?

And `dpkg -l | grep nginx` returns following ...

> ii  nginx-common                              1.2.6-1ubuntu3                         all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
>   ii  nginx-full                                1.2.6-1ubuntu3                         i386         nginx web/proxy server (standard version)

EDIT: I installed it from the source.

Comment: The package names you need to remove/purge are apparently `nginx-full` and `nginx-common`, not just simply `nginx`... You can verify that with `dpkg -S $(which nginx)`.

Comment: @twalberg Well yeah, You are absolutely right. It worked for me. Please put your comment as answer, I ll mark it close. Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As your output from `dpkg -l` shows, the package names involved are actually `nginx-full` and `nginx-common`, not just simply `nginx`. These are the packages that need to be removed.

To find the package that contains a particular program (e.g. `nginx`), you can always run `dpkg -S $(which nginx)`.

Comment: as an alternative to `dpkg -S $(which nginx)`, could do `dpkg -l | grep nginx`

Comment: @ironicaldiction Yes, you can, but that may potentially list several packages, where `dpkg -S $(which nginx)` will list the single package that the `nginx` program is contained in...

Comment: good catch. just thinking if you wanted to purge all the files concerned from your system. @twalberg